# Yii2 dynamically add behavior by class name or instance?

Tags: yii2

I am using behaviors and add them dynamically which is working fine.
To add a a behavior, one can use

```
$component->attachBehavior('myBehavior1', new MyBehavior);
```

or

```
$component->attachBehavior('myBehavior2', MyBehavior::className());
```

I cannot figure out when to use which method or is there no difference? Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there no difference:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html#attachBehavior()-detail

> yii\base\Behavior attachBehavior( $name, $behavior )
>
> $behavior (   string|array|yii\base\Behavior  ) The
> behavior configuration. This can be one of the following:
>
> - a yii\base\Behavior object
> - a string specifying the behavior class
> - an object configuration array that will be passed to Yii::createObject()
>   to create the behavior object.